# How to Encrypt and Decrypt cookie in an Existing Project without changing all pages code

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, encryption, httpcookie

I am working on a project with 1000s of pages in it which uses cookies. Now There comes an security issue , so I am planning to encrypt the cookie and decrypt when use it in page level.

Sample code i have used in **Login page** where my cookie gets created is as below:

```
Response.Cookies.Clear()
Response.Cookies("userinfo")("username") = "Pravin Kumar"
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
```

Now i wanna access that cookie in my **HOME.aspx** page . The code is as below.

```
Response.Write(Request.Cookies("userinfo")("username"))
```

This is how my project pages working till now and this enables user to view cookie in browser window like below : 
[image: Browser Cookie]

Now My intention is i want to do some encrypting in LOGIN.aspx page and do the decryption in such a centralized place so that i no need to change all pages .

PS: I have tried with GLOBAL.asax page using

```
Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

But it didn't helped out.Pls suggest me if any simplest method found.

Comment: are you using forms authentication?

Comment: even if you encrypt cookie how you want to decrypt it in client side? the only logical approach is using javascript for decrypting but you need to update codes a lot. I don't think you can pass cookie value to client side with a minimum changes....

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use HttpModule to override the behavior of the cookie read/write.

here is the sample code:

firstly, in your HttpModule

```
public class CookieEncryptModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestContent += Context_PreSendRequestContent;
        context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
        for (int i = 0; i < httpApplication.Request.Cookies.Count; i++)
        {
            var cookie = httpApplication.Request.Cookies[i];
            cookie.Value = dencryptCookieValue(cookie.Value);
        }
    }



    private void Context_PreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
        for (int i = 0; i < httpApplication.Response.Cookies.Count; i++)
        {
            var cookie = httpApplication.Response.Cookies[i];
            cookie.Value = encryptCookieValue(cookie.Value);
        }
    }


    private string encryptCookieValue(string value)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    }

    private string dencryptCookieValue(string value)
    {
        try
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(value));
        }
        catch
        {
            //in case some system generated cookies like session id will not be encrypted by our code
            return value;
        }

    }

}
```

then in your web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules>
  <add name="encryptCookie" type="[your_namespace].CookieEncryptModule, [your_assemably_name]"/>
</modules></system.webServer>
```

after above is done,
you cookies now will be stored in client with base64,

but to you server side codes it's transparent, you don't need to change anything

[notice]: this will make all JS fail to read the cookie value